# How do I write an async Update method to pass two parameters using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await, restsharp

I'm working on a robotics application on Unity and I want to pass two parameters continuously from my app to a client. The code I've written causes the app to run extremely slowly (about 1 frame per 5 seconds) and it must be an issue with my async requests, but I'm not exactly sure where the problem is:

```
 async void FixedUpdate ()
{
 
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/rw/motionsystem/mechunits/ROB_1?action=mechunit-position");

        client.Timeout = -1;

        client.CookieContainer = login_cookie;

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;v=2.0");

        request.AddParameter("rob_joint", manualjog);
        request.AddParameter("ext_joint", "[0,0,0,0,0,0]");

        var restResponse = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
   

}
```

Comment: I guess what happens is that Unity `FixedUpdate` is not called like a normal method but rather by the messaging system -> it will be executed synchronous and await the request ... For your purpose in general it sounds like using a TCP / UDP protocol in a dedicated thread would be better .. even when sticking to the http/rest API a dedicated thread would probably be better for this .. that `manualjog` what is it and how often is it really updated? In general sounds like you might being hitting a bandwidth limit

Comment: [Avoid `async void` methods](https://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/). Beyond that, we need to see how your method is called.

Comment: manualjog is a string that has the format of [axis1, axis2, axis3, axis4, axis5, axis6]. I update it via void Update with a boolean that turns the update on/off depending if I'm gonna be using the string. 


@RichardDeeming FixedUpdate is called 50 times per second. I omitted a boolean that turns the updating on/off depending on whether I want to make async calls, but when it's on the method is called automatically 50 times per second.

Comment: If you're making 50 calls/sec, and each call takes more than 20ms to complete, you're going to be building up a massive queue of requests. Your memory usage will be steadily climbing, and your performance will drop significantly. You need to measure your requests to make sure they're not taking too long to complete.

Comment: I just solved it with a dedicated function and a while loop. Thank you very much to you both for pointing out that the problem is in FixedUpdate! Here's the working code:

Comment: public async void SyncMechanicalUnits() {

        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/rw/motionsystem/mechunits/ROB_1?action=mechunit-position");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        client.CookieContainer = login_cookie;

        while (solveron == true)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

           //headers

            request.AddParameter("rob_joint", manualjog);
            request.AddParameter("ext_joint", "[0,0,0,0,0,0]");

            var restResponse = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
        }

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it with a dedicated function and a while loop. The issue, as pointed out, was in FixedUpdate. Here's the working code:

```
public async void SyncMechanicalUnits() {

    var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/rw/motionsystem/mechunits/ROB_1?action=mechunit-position");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    client.CookieContainer = login_cookie;

    while (solveron == true)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;v=2.0");

        request.AddParameter("rob_joint", manualjog);
        request.AddParameter("ext_joint", "[0,0,0,0,0,0]");

        var restResponse = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
    }
```